# Can I open app from android browser and return the result back?

Tags: android, browser

I have a following scenario: I'm on android device with a website opened in the browser. This website lets me upload my avatar (or any picture) but I would like to take it from my app (let's assume I have an app which is integrated with my Dropbox).

Is there a way I can click on the link in browser to open an app and then return result (user picture) back to the browser?

I know how to open an app using intent-filter and I know how to open a browser from app using ACTION_VIEW. But I need this full way communication browser->app->(same)browser

Thanks a lot!

Comment: u want to navigate Like : Browser->Android_APP->to Same Browser Page. 
Well I am an iOS developer, Know Android little. But you can go from Browser to Android APP. Just read about Custom URL Schemes. By CLicking the Link you can take the control directly to Android App. You have to set Url Scheme in your App and then Use that url Scheme in the Link. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for info. As I said though, I know how to open app from browser. But I'm not sure if it's possible to return a result.

Comment: I don't see how that could be possible

Comment: I have the same probleme, have you find a solution ?